# Validation of First name and surname

Tags: jquery, regex

i want to check if the value of a variable is not all text for example if the variable is not equal to text then show an error message:

```
if   ( ($(regname).match(/[^a-z ]/gi)) ) {
                $('p.validfirstname').fadeIn(300);
}
```

I'm not sure how to do it so the code above is probably wrong.

Comment: a variable, for example var regname ="Henry1"

Comment: if `regname = "Henry1"` - what is `$(regname)` supposed to do?  I think you just want regname.match

Comment: I'm just trying to find out if the variable is not equal to a alphabetic characters, ie if it has numbers or characters such as -/= etc. A valid name.

Answer (score 2):

It would be something like:

```
var matches = $(regname).val().match(/[^a-zA-Z]/g);


if(matches && matches.length > 0) {
// valid first name
}
```

This is going on the assumption that regname is a CSS selector for an input field. If it isn't an input element use `.text()` instead of `.val()`. And if it isn't an HTML element that you are grabbing a value from, then just call `.match()` on `regname` directly.

If you are storing both first and last names as a single string it might be better to `split()` it before checking for non alphabetic characters.

```
function checkNames()
{
    var firstAndLast = $(regname).val().split(' ');
    var first = firstAndLast[0];
    var last = firstAndLast[1];

    if(checkName(first))
    {
  // valid first name
    }
    if(checkName(last))
    {
      // valid last name
    }
}

function checkName(name)
{
    var matches = $(regname).val().match(/[^a-zA-Z]/g);
    if(matches && matches.length > 0)
    {
        return true;
    } else return false;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/^[A-Za-z]*$/.test(string);
```

If your string has all the alphabets then true else false.